# How to update the background color of the cells from a list view with checkboxes in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

So, I have got a list view in JavaFX and I have added a checkbox to each cell.

```
listView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(new Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(String item) {
        BooleanProperty observable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        observable.addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> selected.add(item));

        return observable;
    }
}));
```

After I do some processing I need to be able to change the background color for each cell depending on some results (the colors are green/red)
I have found a way of doing that:

```
listView.setCellFactory(list -> {
    return new ListCell() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (passed.contains(item))
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: green; -fx-text-fill: white");
            else
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-text-fill: white");

            setText((String) item);
        }
    };
});
```

The problem is that this sets new cells for the list view and removes the checkboxes.

Is it possible somehow to change the background colors and keep the checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
listView.setCellFactory(list -> new CheckBoxListCell(item -> {
    BooleanProperty observable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    observable.addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) ->
            selected.add(item)
    );
    return observable;
}) {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (passed.contains(item)){
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: green; -fx-text-fill: white");
            setText((String) item);
        }else {
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-text-fill: white");
            setText((String) item);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In my case it worked with public void updateItem(...)

Comment: @RaduAramă Yes, sorry. In `ListCell` the method is `protected`, but (for no apparent reason) in `CheckBoxListCell` it is `public`

Comment: What 'passed' means ?

Comment: @LucianoBrum No idea, I was copying it from the original post. It’s not really relevant to what was being asked here, is it?